# Jmeter doesn't interpreter machineName() variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I faced with a strange issue. I need a jmeter to generate jtl and log files where name of the file will be hostname where jmeter is running on. For this task I found internal variable "__machineName()" in my case it works but only partially. Below is example:
 `jmeter ... -l ${__machineName()}.jtl -j ${__machineName()}.log`
But result is a bit strange:
`${__machineName()}.log   328-15-09-2020-15-02-42-95r4v.jtl`
It works but **only for jtl** file! I've tried other variables and had the same result.
Have you faced with such issues?

Additional info: execution of jmeter is wrapped in the script that receives all properties as string and just execute it, therefore ideas about usage of shell commands won't work. Result will look the following way:
`` `hostname`.log `` or `${HOSTANME}.log`

Workflow:

1. Python generate string with paramaters for jmeter execution. I'm using Jinja here. Part of the code:

```
Template(  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
        -l {{ log_dir }}/${__machineName()}.jtl \
        -j {{ log_dir }}/${__machineName()}.log)
```

2. Python schedule Kubernetes Job and pass string with properties to the jmeter
3. Container with jmeter has entrypoint script here it set some Java params and start jmeter. Part where jmeter receives string with properties:

```
...
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmn${n}m -Xms${s}m -Xmx${x}m"
jmeter $@
```

4. Jmeter execute test with specific params and write logs. Exactly here I faced with a problem that ${__machineName()} works ok for -l(jtl log) param and doesn't work for -j(log) param.

Answer (score 1):

The function will not be executed as it's between your shell and [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) logging system, you need to fix your shell script in order to be able to shell commands.

If for some reason you cannot amend your shell script it should be possible to change JMeter logging configuration so it would contain [environment variable lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html)

Necessary changes to [log4j2.xml file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/log4j2.xml) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

1. Add this block to define `HOSTNAME` property reading the underlying OS environment variable

   ```
   <Properties>
       <Property name="HOSTNAME">${env:HOSTNAME}</Property>
   </Properties>
   ```
2. Change this line:

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${HOSTNAME}.log" append="false">
   ```

   [image]

   so next time you start your test JMeter will create the log file with using your machine hostname as the filename and you won't have to pass it via command-line argument.

More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to Jmeter configuration. I have incoming properties then generating string with all params to run Jmeter and only after passing this string to Jmeter for execution.  
One **important** thing from my side I want to mention that **this function works, but only for jtl file, for log file neither this or other variables don't work**. This is the main oddity I was talking about.

Comment: So what do you want? If you need help you need to show your script and the way it's being used, otherwise the continuation of discussion doesn't make sense

Comment: Header of the question was updated. Hope it's enough to understand.

Comment: If it's Python you can just change `${__machineName()}` to [`platform.uname().node`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.node)

Comment: then it will pass to the script hostname of the machine from which this script was executed.